# 403 Directory_QuotaExceeded when trying to add permissions for more than 50 APIs to an AAD Application Registration

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I am trying to add a tad more than 50 APIs (and respective permissions) to an AAD Application Registration on an Azure Premium Sub, be it in an automated fashion via Powershell, or old-school style (manually via Azure Portal). This result in an error : Quota exceeded

My question, alas not directly Programing Related, has someone reached this hard limit of 50 APIs for an AppReg and found a way to override it ?

Subsequent question: as the error message suggest (see screenshots), there seems to exist a "global application object limit" or a Quota defined somewhere in the AAD - but no documentation has been found about this very subject - anyone with knowledge about this AAD quota configuration ?

For what it's worth, I wrote an error reproducing Powershell script that creates a first AppReg, then 51 others, each with one AppRole, and finally tries to add the 51 AppRoles as APIs (+ permissions) on the first Appreg, it fails when updating the primary AppReg with more than 51 APIs (+ permissions) - below 51 everything goes smoothly

[Screenshot 01 - Powershell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3HUnH.png) - [Screenshot 02 - Azure Portal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sjpie.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Limits on the number of configured API permissions for an application registration will be enforced starting in October 2021**

> The total number of required permissions for any single application
> registration must not exceed 400 permissions and The existing limit on
> the number of distinct APIs for which permissions are required remains
> unchanged and can’t exceed 50 APIs.

Reference: https://www.michev.info/Blog/Post/3494/maximum-number-of-api-permissions-for-an-azure-ad-integrated-app

A non-admin user can create no more than 250 Azure AD resources. Both active resources and deleted resources that are available to restore count toward this quota. Only deleted Azure AD resources that were deleted fewer than 30 days ago are available to restore. Deleted Azure AD resources that are no longer available to restore count toward this quota at a value of one-quarter for 30 days.

> create a custom role with permission to create an unlimited number of
> app registrations, and then assign that role to a user. The assigned
> user can then use the Azure portal, Azure AD PowerShell, or Microsoft
> Graph API to create application registrations

**custom role grants the ability to create an unlimited number of application registrations
The least privileged role required to create and assign Azure AD custom roles is the Privileged Role Administrator.**

Example to Create Custom role through portal

**1)** Sign in to the [Azure portal](https://ms.portal.azure.com/) or [Azure AD admin center](https://aad.portal.azure.com/).

**2)** Select **Azure Active Directory** --> **Roles and administrators** and then **select New custom role**.

[image]

**3)**  On the Basics tab, provide **Application Registration Creator** for the name of the role and **Can create an unlimited number of application registrations** for the role description, and then select Next.

[image]

**4)** On the Permissions tab, enter **"microsoft.directory/applications/create"** in the search box, and then select the checkboxes next to the desired permissions, and then select **Next**.

[image]

**5)** On the **Review + create tab**, review the permissions and select **Create**.

**Assign the role**

**1)** Sign in to the Azure portal or Azure AD admin center.

**2)** Select **Azure Active Directory** > **Roles and administrators.**

**3)** Select the **Application Registration Creator role** and select **Add assignment**.

**4)** Select the desired **user** and click Select to add the user to the role.

For more details refer this documents

1)https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/roles/quickstart-app-registration-limits

2)https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/enterprise-users/directory-service-limits-restrictions

Comment: Thanks for answering, I'm aware of this, but this is not what I'm asking for, it's not about creating AppRegs or a limitation of the number of Appregs one can create, rather it's about adding more than 50 APIs (+ permissions) to a single AppReg

Comment: Hi 0xff, I edited my answer,  you can  add the 400 permission and 50  APIs for sing App registration  as mentioned in the  document :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/application?view=graph-rest-1.0&viewFallbackFrom=graph-rest-v1.0

Comment: If the answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you